# SignalR for Server-to-Server Communication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a load-balanced web application which already uses SignalR for a few Server-to-Client push notifications.

Can I leverage SignalR's backplane to provide server-to-server communication?  I would like to have certain methods invoked on all servers, and this process could be requested by a web request from any one server.  An example would be invalidating a cache entry.

Comment: I'm not shure if understand you correct. Do you have a "master-server"? If yes the other server can also be a client of the masterserver. How to write a c# client  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Comment: You might be able to, but it would be odd. You could make a hidden hub and use a custom pipeline to pick up messages directed at it. It all sounds a little weird though to be honest...